# FFmpeg: Drawtext with unique text per frame?

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I have a file containing an list of strings that I'd like to burn on with FFmpeg.  I need the first string to be burned onto the first frame in the file, the second string to be burned onto the second frame, etc.  There are cases where I could theoretically have hundreds of thousands of frames, and each will need to have a unique string burned on.  The strings do not have a pattern in them - but I do know what they all should be when I am ready to write the file. I will always have the same number of frames that I do strings to burn on.

I would ideally like to solve this with the drawtext filter (as it would make my life easier for other things I am doing), but I will be happy for any solution that can solve this problem.

I've explored the following options, but nothing seems to fit my needs perfectly:

- Using drawtext with a specific string of text= for every individual frame

  - Doesn't work because the command becomes too long for windows to accept via the command line
- Using drawtext with a textfile

  - (doesn't work because it can't be "reloaded" with updated text on every frame
- Using a subtitle format like ASS

  - This might work for most of my use-cases, but I do have some files that have a variable frame rate which makes this a much harder problem to solve.

I'd really prefer doing this all in FFmpeg, but I'm beginning to think it may not be possible.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: IIRC, this may have been asked someone on Stack Exchange, but I didn't find it and I don't know if it got answered. The [sendcmd](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#sendcmd_002c-asendcmd) filter could possibly do it. I'm not able to try it now. See [Sendcmd in ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49600924/) and [FFmpeg drawtext filter - is it possible to use variables with live data for x,y coordinates?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55966056/) for some related examples.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was unaware of this filter, but that looks so close to what I need. I just ran a test and was able to get it to "work", but unfortunately I'm only able to get it to work with 'time' and not with 'frames'.

I.E. I can get it to work by displaying one string for "1 second", and then the next for another "1 second" - but I can't figure out how to do it only for "first frame", and then new text for "second frame".  Any thoughts on whether that's possible or not?

Comment: maybe, unpack to PNGs, draw text, and pack em to video? script